# Tkinter - Make status bar longer than window

Tags: python, tkinter

I was working on a Tkinter GUI with a status bar at the bottom to display instructions or the file paths on hover over a specific widget, especially if the file path was too long to write in the given section. Is there any way that the status bar could extends past the window in the case of a long name? (Like maybe a window without the top bar?)

The status bar is cut off at the end: 
[image: Status bar is cut off]

What I want the status bar to look like:
[image]

I've seen other applications where the status bar can extend past the window but I was wondering if that was possible in Tkinter. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x500-500+50")
root.config(bg="lightblue")

stslabel = Label(root, anchor=W, 
              text="Process another input file to get citations. blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah"
              )
stslabel.pack(fill=X, side=BOTTOM)
```

All you need to do is using the most proper geometry manager (`pack` in this case) for the `label` widget that is intended to show a status (`ststlabel`); then adding some options to the geometry manager: `fill` makes it extended as you stretch the window horizontally; and `side` puts it at the very bottom of the screen which means it will always stay there (until you make the geometry of any of preceding widgets to bottom. Otherwise, it'll be replaced with that).

Now we got it! But there is a problem that it doesn't show the beginning of the status text. To solve this add an `anchor` option to the status label and change its value to `W` since we want to see the beginning (the most left side) of the text. And `W` which stands for "West", *does* it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What I meant was to have the label extend past the width of the screen without having to resize the screen kind of so it sticks out if the text is longer than the screen size. The picture above is what I currently have in my code. Any tips?

Comment: Oh, so the picture above doesn't show what you want to get but what you currently get?

Comment: Yeah, it was kind of misleading TBH. But anyway. Could you please describe what you want to get with a picture like you did with what you have got now?

Comment: Okay I added another pic :)

Comment: If it goes out of the window screen, where will it be shown then? Let me guess, you want it to get cut off when it reaches the most right border of the screen?

Comment: I want it to be cut after the length of the text. Like I said in my question, I thought a potential solution would be to make the status bar another window without the title bar. I just found a the method `root.overridedirect(1)` to disable the title bar. I'm just not sure if this is the best way to go about it.

Comment: Can you make it in HTML/CSS?

Comment: `root.overrideredirect(1)` does something different than what you are asking. It's just used to prevent the window manager from decorating the window. In other words, the window will not have a title or a border, and it cannot be moved or closed via ordinary means.

Comment: I meant to use `root.overridedirect` for only the status bar part. And no, the window is part of this project: https://github.com/BioDataSorter/BioDataSorter  Thanks for the help though!

Comment: No, that is not possible in Tkinter, at least, as far as I know. Because the parent window covers everything intact inside it, like if you make it `overridedirect`-ed, then everything inside it will become `overridedirect`-ed. Looks like a great project BTW! Good luck!

Comment: Additionally, if you have another widget, like `text`, you can make the status label extended past the text widget: http://pastebin.com/zemA3hCL But again, it's not possible to extend past the parent window since it bundles everything inside itself as a whole.